# Where is onclick event function?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I'm new to magento. I go through the **Catalog->Manage Products** module to understand the coding & design, i seen that everything (design and coding and controller actions) in block and controllers is there except submit button code?

can you anyone tell me where is the submit button design & code and how that button works?

**if I added the custom action to perform that action where I write code?**

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is something you can find around `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class, check it's `_prepareMassaction` method. This is where that button comes from.

Specifically, for products grid page check out file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` for better understanding.

This is specific part of code in that file that reflects as "Delete" item in dropdown on your screen:

```
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));
```